# Bundler error when deploying Rails 6 App to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, bundle, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been struggling getting around the well known `bundler 2.0.x` error when deploying to both Heroku and AWS Elastic Beanstalk. After trying many of the suggested remedies like updating gems and installing bundler 2.0.x or `bundler update --system`. None of this has worked so far. I found a solution to create a file in `.ebextensions` like so:

```
files:

# Runs before \./10_bundle_install.sh`:`

"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/09_gem_install_bundler.sh" :

mode: "000775"

owner: root

group: users

content: |

#!/usr/bin/env bash



EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir)

EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)

# Source the application's ruby, i.e. 2.6. Otherwise it will be 2.3, which will give this error: \bundler requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0``

. $EB_SCRIPT_DIR/use-app-ruby.sh



cd $EB_APP_STAGING_DIR

echo "Installing compatible bundler"

gem install bundler -v 2.1.0.pre.2
```

This is the error I'm still getting on `eb deploy staging-1`:

```
Creating application version archive "app-7b50-191111_122622".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
2019-11-11 17:28:21    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2019-11-11 17:28:28    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2019-11-11 17:31:36    ERROR   [Instance: i-0ba40e32901557bee] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...ystem, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.1.0.pre.2`
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `activate_bin_path'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2019-11-11 17:31:36    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2019-11-11 17:31:36    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0ba40e32901557bee'. Aborting the operation.
2019-11-11 17:31:37    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.        

ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
[12:31:40] (master) tml_portal
// ♥ eb deploy staging-1
Creating application version archive "app-7b50-191111_123229".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
2019-11-11 17:34:45    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2019-11-11 17:34:53    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2019-11-11 17:37:47    ERROR   [Instance: i-0ba40e32901557bee] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...ystem, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.1.0.pre.2`
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `activate_bin_path'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2019-11-11 17:37:47    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2019-11-11 17:37:47    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0ba40e32901557bee'. Aborting the operation.
2019-11-11 17:37:48    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.        

ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

Any ideas on how to get around this dreaded Bundler issue for deployment?

Comment: Any luck?  I'm getting a similar error...

Answer (score 0):

It still the missing bundle version error. Could you try following:

```
#.ebextensions/bundler_update.config

commands:
  update_bundler:
    command: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/gem install bundler -v 2.1.0.pre.2
```

Ruby and Bundler version should match yours.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've tried that and still no luck. Would love to get a live chat going with someone on this seeing that I'm on a deadline to get an app deployed (This is a new app).